# Make Firefox automatically focus submit button?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

When I go to a form using Chrome it seems to automatically prefil the form and focus the submit button so that I can just pressenter to submit.

Is it possible to mimic this feature in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only half an answer:
I'm not aware of anything that can do exactly what you want (though it's not impossible for an extension to achieve, I don't think there is one yet).

[Autofill Forms](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autofill-forms/) is a pretty good extension for its kind and it has an option for "focus on last field that was auto-filled" which is often one 'tab' away from the submit button.
It's also highly customisable with JavaScript so maybe something can be done to change the last focus placement.
And of course this feature can be suggested to the developers of the extension and they might make it some day.

Answer (score 1):

[GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) if you need it for a specific site, [LastPass](http://lastpass.com/) for anything more generic...